# what is wrong in this code for dynamic programming?

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

hello this is my first time posting in this community

so, what i need to do is:

write a function canSum() that takes in a target sum and an array of numbers as arguments.

the function should return a boolean indicating whether or not it is possible to generate the target sum using numbers from the array.

you may use an element of the array as many times as needed

you may assume that all input numbers are nonnegative.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(canSum(7, new int[]{2, 3}));         //true
        System.out.println(canSum(7, new int[]{5, 3, 4, 7}));   //true
        System.out.println(canSum(7, new int[]{2, 4}));         //false
        System.out.println(canSum(8, new int[]{2, 3, 5}));      //true
        System.out.println(canSum(300, new int[]{7, 14}));      //false

    }
    private static Map<Integer, Boolean> memo = new HashMap<>();

    public static boolean canSum(int target, int[] arr){

        if(memo.containsKey(target)) return memo.get(target);
        if(target == 0) return true;
        if(target < 0) return false;

        for(int i = 0; i< arr.length;i++){
            int remainder = target - arr[i];
            if(canSum(remainder,arr)){
                memo.put(target, true);
                return true;
            }
        }
        memo.put(target,false);
        return false;
    }
```

the program outputs:
true
true
true
true
true

when it should be:
true
true
false
true
false

Comment: Your first method call will result in a Map.Entry with {7,true}. In your second and third call this entry in the map will deliver true as result.

Comment: **2 + 3  aint 7 at all, not even close to it, why should it return true ???!?!?**

Comment: @GiorgosXou As far as I understand numbers can be used more than once. So 2+2+3=7

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS True, my fault lol, thanks

Comment: *\*I was in a hurry to answer\**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you never clear your `Map<Integer, Boolean> memo` between your method calls. Your map that saves if a sum can be generated with true or false is only valid for one method run, so your code should not reuse the same map between different calls.

One simple fix would be to manually clear the map after every call:

```
System.out.println(canSum(7, new int[] { 2, 3 })); //true
memo.clear();
System.out.println(canSum(7, new int[] { 5, 3, 4, 7 })); //true
memo.clear();
System.out.println(canSum(7, new int[] { 2, 4 })); //false
memo.clear();
System.out.println(canSum(8, new int[] { 2, 3, 5 })); //true
memo.clear();
System.out.println(canSum(300, new int[] { 7, 14 })); //false
memo.clear();
```

will create the output

```
true
true
false
true
false
```

A more elegant solution would be to not use a field to store the map, but create it internally when needed. You could do it like this with 2 methods for example:

```
public static boolean canSum(int target, int[] arr) {
    Map<Integer, Boolean> memo = new HashMap<>();
    return canSum(target, arr, memo);
}

private static boolean canSum(int target, int[] arr, Map<Integer, Boolean> memo) {
    if (memo.containsKey(target)) {
        return memo.get(target);
    }
    if (target == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    if (target < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int remainder = target - arr[i];
        if (canSum(remainder, arr, memo)) {
            memo.put(target, true);
            return true;
        }
    }
    memo.put(target, false);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: in the part when you created two methods, was that an OOP concept?

Answer (score 2):

Don't take memo as static

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(canSum(7, new int[]{2, 3}));         //true
        System.out.println(canSum(7, new int[]{5, 3, 4, 7}));   //true
        System.out.println(canSum(7, new int[]{2, 4}));         //false
        System.out.println(canSum(8, new int[]{2, 3, 5}));      //true
        System.out.println(canSum(300, new int[]{7, 14}));      //false

    }
    /* 
     * private static Map<Integer, Boolean> memo = new HashMap<>(); 
     * 
     * It will check for first one and will store the result, then for rest
     * operation it will rend stored data only
     */

    public static boolean canSum(int target, int[] arr){
        
        Map<Integer, Boolean> memo = new HashMap<>();

        if(memo.containsKey(target)) return memo.get(target);
        if(target == 0) return true;
        if(target < 0) return false;

        for(int i = 0; i< arr.length;i++){
            int remainder = target - arr[i];
            if(canSum(remainder,arr)){
                memo.put(target, true);
                return true;
            }
        }
        memo.put(target,false);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not working since your `memo` map is a static member variable that will contain all the previous iterations as well.

Hence when you did `memo.put()` in the last line, it added different combinations in that which were reused directly in `memo.containsKey`.

You can move that variable inside that function. It should start working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the  memo object as a function parameter and set its default value to None. Then There would be no confusion of Global scope and clearing the memo object each time you call the function.

simple pseudocode:

```
def canSum(targetSum: int, numbers: list[int], memo=Optional[dict] = None) -> Bool:
    # Memo Checking Logic
    if memo is None:
        memo = {}

    # Base Cases
    # Memo Fetching Logic
    if targetSum in memo:
        return memo[targetSum]

    if targetSum < 0:
        return False

    if targetSum == 0:
        return True

    # Recursive Case
    for num in numbers:
        remainder = targetSum - num
        # Memo Caching Logic
        if canSum(remainder, numbers, memo):
            memo[targetSum] = True
            return True

    memo[targetSum] = False
    return False
```